# How to make Snipping Tool using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I'm new in OpenLayers and would like to know how to make something like Windows' Snipping Tool.

I have a map and need the tool that would be able to draw rectangle over the map, make screen shot and load it in another area.

That would be done using JavaScript.

I've tried to find something similar on Internet, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a combination these examples https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html where the cropped canvas is exported as a PNG but you could do whatever you wish with it.

```js
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  });


  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  });

  // a normal select interaction to handle click
  var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
  map.addInteraction(select);

  var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();

  // a DragBox interaction used to select features by drawing boxes
  var dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
    condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly
  });

  map.addInteraction(dragBox);

  dragBox.on('boxend', function() {

    // convert geometry to pixels (extent doesn't gives correct bounds when view is rotated)

    var left = Infinity;
    var top = Infinity;
    var bottom = -Infinity;
    var right = -Infinity;

    dragBox.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0].forEach(function(coord) {
      var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coord);
      left = Math.min(left, pixel[0]);
      right = Math.max(right, pixel[0]);
      top = Math.min(top, pixel[1]);
      bottom = Math.max(bottom, pixel[1]);
    });

    map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {
      var image = event.context.canvas;
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = right - left;
      canvas.height = bottom - top;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(image, left, top, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), 'map.png');
      } else {
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
        });
      }
    });
    map.renderSync();
  });
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.ol-dragbox {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-color: rgba(100,150,0,1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```